# Get date and time from two Nebula CDateTime Widgets

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nebula

How would you read date and time from two Nebula CDateTime widgets? 
[image]

Here's my own answer, but I am sure there is a more efficient solution:

```
    final Calendar calResult = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Calendar calDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Calendar calTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    calResult.clear();
    calDate.clear();
    calTime.clear();

    // read date
    calDate.setTime(cdtDate.getSelection());
    final int year = calDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month = calDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day = calDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // read time
    calTime.setTime(cdtTime.getSelection());
    final int hour = calTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int minute = calTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    final int second = calTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    // set date
    calResult.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calResult.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calResult.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

    // set time
    calResult.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calResult.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calResult.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);

    // return Date object
    Date result = calResult.getTime();
```

Comment: Get the first date (`calDate`) and only set the hours, minutes, seconds? Why do you want to change your code?

Comment: @jhamon I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.